# Serve index.html implicitly with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, static-files

I have a simple Spring Boot Starter Web application.
I want to serve several static html files.

I know that I could serve static files with Spring Boot just simply putting then to `/static` subdirectory of my `src/main/resources`.

When I create file (for example) `/static/docs/index.html`, then I could access it via `http://localhost:8080/docs/index.html`.

What I want to achieve is to access this file simply with `http://localgost:8080/docs` where `index.html` is implicitly added by Spring.

#### Summary:

I need to serve static files in `/static/{path}/index.html` in resources via `localhost:8080/{path}` path.

---

I know that I could manually create mappings in controllers, but when there is many files to serve it becomes annoying.

Comment: Create one controller that automatically maps all of them?

Comment: Did you find a way to do it?

Comment: @geschema no, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/docs").setViewName("forward:/docs/index.html");
    }
}
```

Or possible solution for all static subdirs (ugly version)

```
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    File file;
    try {
        file = new ClassPathResource("static").getFile();
        String[] names = file.list();

        for(String name : names)
        {
            if (new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + name).isDirectory())
            {
                registry.addViewController("/" + name).setViewName("forward:/" + name +"/index.html");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO: handle error
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it still requires to create mapping per path.

Comment: or you could get all directories from static folder and call this line dynamically for each directory if you want have permanent solution. It is not nice but effective.